# Java Quarkus AWS-SNS Topic does not exist

Tags: java, quarkus, amazon-sns

Getting topic not found upon publishing a message to SNS.

The credentails configured via CLI is correct as well.

```
PS C:\quarkus-project> aws sns list-topics
{
    "Topics": [
        {
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:655163477595:test-sns-topic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my application.properties

```
quarkus.sns.aws.region=ap-southeast-1
quarkus.sns.aws.credentials.type=default
test.sns.notification=arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:655163477595:test-sns-topic
```

And here is the code for publishing to SNS

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.PublishResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.SnsException;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class TestService {

    @Inject
    private SnsClient sns;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "test.sns.notification")
    private String topicArn;

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Inject
    private Logger LOG;


    public void sendPostingCreationToSns(String message) {
        try {
     
            PublishResponse response = sns.publish(p -> p.topicArn(topicArn).message(message));
            LOG.info(response.toString());
        }
        catch (SnsException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

But getting the message

```
(vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) Topic does not exist (Service: Sns, Status Code: 404, Requ
est ID: 17137412-88b3-4d4b-b415-f694f88a9966)
```

What seems to be the problem? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Already solved. I just upgrade the artifact version of SNS